# Squid on an Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machine, squid, azure

I can't get it to work. Here's exactly what I did:

1. Create a new Azure VM, Windows Server 2012.
2. RDP to the new VM
3. Download & Extract Squid for Windows (2.7.STABLE8)
4. Rename the conf files (squid, mime & cachemgr)
5. Add the following lines on the end of squid.conf

> auth_param basic program c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth.exe c:/squid/etc/passwd.txt
>   auth_param basic children 5
>   auth_param basic realm Welcome to http://abcde.fg Squid Proxy!
>   auth_param basic credentialsttl 12 hours
>   auth_param basic casesensitive off
>   acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
>   http_access allow ncsa_users

6. Use http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator-windows/ to create passwd.txt
7. Test passwd.txt via c:/squid/libexec/ncsa_auth.exe c:/squid/etc/passwd.txt (success)
8. squid -z
9. squid -i
10. net start squid (No errors so far).
11. go to https://manage.windowsazure.com, Virtual Machines -> myVM -> Endpoints
12. Add Endpoint:

> Name: Squid
>   Protocol: TCP
>   Public Port: 80
>   Private Port: 3128

That's it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I think I screwed something up at the endpoint? I'm not sure.. help?

EDIT: I'm testing it via Firefox -> Options -> Advanced -> Network, and the exact error is "The Proxy Server is refusing connections." I'm using my DNS as the Proxy server "abcdef.cloudapp.net" and port 80 (since that's my public endpoint).

Answer (score 1):

Is port 80 open in the Windows Firewall?

For example, from an elevated command prompt you could run the following to enable port 80 inbound:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=HTTP dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80
```

To test if a port is listening is with PsPing:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/jj729731.aspx

```
psping abcdef.cloudapp.net:80
```

Comment: I already configured the firewall to allow port 80. I tried psping, and the Azure VM still refuses the network connection :(